# Java RMI has different values in same instance

Tags: java, rmi

We implemented a little application where clients make call a method on the server. The idea is that the server keeps a list of variables to be called, we stripe off a value once it has been called.

In our instance we need to have the client call first with "m1" and then with "m2". the method justReceived (over RMI).

```
public class Server implements TestService, Serializable {
  private HashMap<String, List<String>> assertQueue = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

  @Override
  public synchronized void justReceived(Message m, String from, String to) {
    if (!assertQueue.containsKey(to) || !(m instanceof TestMessage))
      return;

    TestMessage message = (TestMessage) m;

    if (assertQueue.get(to).get(0).equals(message.message)) {
      assertQueue.get(to).remove(0);
      System.out.println(assertQueue);//p1
    } else {
      testErrors.add(new AssertionError("Expected " + to + " to receive message " + assertQueue.get(to).get(0) + " but got " + message.message));
    }
  }
}
```

We have a separate thread monitoring the assertQueue, but there is no change observed, while we are sure the assertQueue has been altered over RMI.

The other thread keeps printing

```
{c3=[m1, m2]}
```

While at p1 is printed:

```
{c3=[m2]}
```

The other thread keeps printing the same, even after at point p1 the smaller assertQueue has been printed.

Comment: What RMI? Has this object been exported? Why is it `Serializable?`

Comment: registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(serverPort);
     registry.bind("server", this); 
is used to create the service, it is Serializable, because otherwise it gives an error. I use standard java.rmi

Comment: You solved that problem the wrong way: see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no RMI here. This is a `Serializable` object which is transmitted to the client and executes there. Which is the problem. You have a copy of the data structure per client, instead of a single one at the server.

You've forgotten to export it. You need to either:

1. Make it extend `UnicastRemoteObject()`, which in turn will force you to provide a constructor that throws `RemoteException`, or
2. Export it 'manually', with `UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(),` before you call `bind().`

You can remove `implements Serializable`.